# Two virtually calculated columns in view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Initially in a regular table, there are two columns `Key` and `ParentKey`. The `Key` gets its value as an identity column - automatically. `ParentKey` - by the expression

```
 WITH
  latest
  as
(
  SELECT
   ProductID,
   Date,
   [Key],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY  ProductID
          ORDER BY [Date] DESC -- order by latest Date
    ) rn 
  FROM
   [MyTable]
)


UPDATE      
  u 
SET
  u.[ParentKey] = latest.[Key] 
FROM
   [MyTable] u
INNER JOIN
  latest
    ON u.ProductID = latest.ProductID
WHERE
  latest.rn = 1
```

Does it possible to combine both of these two steps simultaneously when creating the View (Key and ParentKey becomes virtual)? I have a solution for the first part of these task -  creating Key column in a view. Could it be combined with the step which then sets ParentKey?

**Current Code**

```
CREATE VIEW v_Test 

AS
SELECT
ProductID
,Date,
CAST (ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY [ProductID] ) AS int) as [Key]

-- some expression for ParentKey?

FROM [MyTable]
```

**Desired View output** (Key and ParentKey must be processed during view creation)

```
+-------------------------------------------------
|ProductID  |   Date        |  Key   |  ParentKey 
+-------------------------------------------------
|111        |   2017-12-31  |   1    |   3
|111        |   2018-12-31  |   2    |   3
|111        |   2019-12-31  |   3    |   3
|222        |   2017-12-31  |   4    |   6
|222        |   2018-12-31  |   5    |   6
|222        |   2019-12-31  |   6    |   6
|333        |   2017-12-31  |   7    |   9
|333        |   2018-12-31  |   8    |   9
|333        |   2019-12-31  |   9    |   9
```

Comment: Generally: Simply define expression like A + B AS Something

Comment: Simple using:  SELECT *, MAX(Key) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID) Key2 FROM (Your Query) x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood what you are trying to do correctly then you can put the query with the row number in a CTE or derived table and then reference that in a windowed aggregate to get the max.

```
CREATE VIEW v_Test
AS
  WITH T
       AS (SELECT ProductID,
                  Date,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ProductID] ASC,  [Date] ASC ) AS [Key]
           FROM   [MyTable])
  SELECT ProductID,
         Date,
         [Key],
         MAX([Key]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ProductID]) AS [ParentKey]
  FROM   T
```

These "Keys" will not be at all stable over time though as they can change after inserts for unrelated products.

Comment: Recursive CTE is the way to go if the keys are likely to change but they can be computationally expensive and there is a limit to the number of recursions, by default it is 100 but can be overrideed with a hint, unless you are in a table function in which case it is fixed at 100.  
Another option would be to add the logic to a trigger.  I am not a big fan of triggers, they can be turned off and have unexpected consequences when using @@IDENTITY but if the relationships never change they might be valid here.

Comment: @AaronReese - If you have an answer post it. Don't leave it as an irrelevant comment on my one. I don't agree recursive CTEs have anything to offer here

Comment: Sorry, my bad,  I scan-read the post and assumed the OP was looking for hierarchical relationship for the chain-of-evidence and your view was using a recursive CTE so was confirming your intent.  You are correct a recursive CTE would be of no benefit here.  Not sure you need the CTE in your query though. the OP says that the key is autopoulated IDENTITY field so you can be sure the MAX(key) is the latest entry.

Comment: @AaronReese - the IDENTITY column is the initial state. ("Initially in a regular table") For some reason they are trying to replace the whole thing with "virtual" columns

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I believe will be much shorter using only MAX with OVER clause. Something like

```
UPDATE      
  u 
SET
  u.[ParentKey] = 
FROM
   [MyTable] u
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX( [Key] OVER ( PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY [DATE] DESC ) LatestKey ) ca
```